# Check cnat. and got Type return

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

All

I am trying to understand the Church numerals, mentioned in the SF-LF book, chp4.

```
Definition cnat := forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X -> X.
Definition one : cnat :=
  fun (X : Type) (f : X -> X) (x : X) => f x.
Check cnat.
Check one.
```

And I get

```
cnat
     : Type
one
     : cnat
```

It seems cnat is some kind of type, and function at the same time. How can it be both type and function? Anyone can help explain a little more about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "`forall (X : Type),`" syntax is a way to form a type, from a type parameterized by `X`. `forall (X : Type), (X -> X) -> X -> X` is **a type of functions**, which given a type `X` produce a value of type `(X -> X) -> X -> X` (which is itself a function).

The "`fun (X : Type) =>`" syntax is a way to form a function, from a term parameterized by `X`. `fun (X : Type) (f : X -> X) (x : X) => f x` is **a function**, which given a type `X` produce the function `fun (f : X -> X) (x : X) => f x` (which is itself a function).

What `fun` and `forall` have in common is that they involve **binders**, like `(X : Type)` (also like `(f : X -> X)`, `(x : X)`). `fun` is a construct that involves binders to form functions, but not all constructs that involve binders form functions: `forall` is a construct that involves binders to form types.